# How to link a javascript function has a herf in wordpress main navigation menu

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress, html

Ok what im trying to do is apply javascript onto one of the main navigation tabs on my website or as wordpress calls it menus. The code that I am trying to use is for a randomizer which is located below.

```
 var random = new Array();

    random[0] = "https://example.com";
    random[1] = "https://example.com";
    random[2] = "https://example.com";
    random[3] = "https://example.com";
    random[4] = "https://example.com";
    random[5] = "https://example.com";

    function randomlink() {
    window.location = random[Math.floor(Math.random()*random.length)];
    }
```

Now getting the javascript on the site isn't the main issue the problem for me is linking it on the wordpress menus.In this example lets assume I just made a new menu in wordpress called Random what I want is for the user to click random in the new navigation tab i just added and be redirected to one of the random pages I added above. If i wasnt using wordpress and this was hard coded I would simply need to add the following:

```
<a href="javascript:randomlink()">Random</a>
```

In order to get the navigation tab or menu called random to work however wordpress doesn't allow me to just add `javascript:randomlink()` as a link to work on the menus section of the page , so i wanted to know how to link this script onto the menus in wordpress
thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1):

You could use jQuery to add an event listener to the links in your navigation that invokes the random link function. This way you're handling the clicks without touching the mark-up.

```
$('.myNav li a').click(function(){
    randomlink();
});
```

Edit: You seem to have removed jQuery from your tags.

```
var elements = document.getElementsByTagName('a');
for(var i = 0, len = elements.length; i < len; i++) {
    elements[i].onclick = function () {
        randomlink();
    }
}
```

Comment: @ChrisChapel The jQuery snippet at the top of my answer is 3 lines which uses jQuery to select all elements that are anchor elements in the hypothetical navigation, (in your code you would use a different selector to maths your navigation) and attach an event handler that calls the function you made whenever someone clicks the links.

Comment: Let us continue this discussion in [chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/163319/how-to-link-a-javascript-function-has-a-herf-in-wordpress-main-navigation-menu)

Comment: Edit your question to include your HTML mark-up then.

Comment: @ChrisChapel that is a ridiculous statement. Giving a stranger on a website access to your entire website. You are not fit to be a site admin if you're willing to compromise your site and its data like that.

Comment: That's still a ridiculous solution to your problem. You should either edit the question to include mark-up or accept my answer. Or both seeings as the answer is correct.